# Complex indirect slice indexing : how to do it?

Tags: numpy, indexing

I'm looking to find a vector formulation instead of a loop for the following problem.

```
import numpy as np

ny = 6 ; nx = 4 ; na = 2
aa = np.array (np.arange (ny*nx), dtype=np.int32)
aa.shape = (ny, nx)

print ( 'aa : ', aa)

# ix1 has length nx
ix1 = np.array ( [0, 2, 1, 3] )
```

For each value of the second index in `aa`, I want to take in `aa` a slice that starts at `ix1`, of length `na`

### With a loop :

##### - 1

```
bb = np.empty ( [na, nx], dtype=np.int32 )
for xx in np.arange (nx) :
    bb [:, xx] = aa [ ix1[xx]:ix1[xx]+na, xx]
print ( 'bb : ', bb)
```

##### - 2

```
bb = np.empty ( [na, nx], dtype=np.int32 )
for xx in np.arange (nx) :
    bb [:, xx] = aa [ slice(ix1[xx],ix1[xx]+na), xx]
print ( 'bb : ', bb)
```

##### - 3

```
bb = np.empty ( [na, nx], dtype=np.int32 )
for xx in np.arange (nx) :
    bb [:, xx] = aa [ np.s_[ix1[xx]:ix1[xx]+na], xx]
print ( 'bb : ', bb)
```

### Is there a vector form of this ?

None of the following works

```
print ( np.ix_ (ix1,ix1+na) )
aa [ np.ix_ (ix1,ix1+na) ]

print ( np.s_ [ix1:ix1+na] )
aa [  np.s_ [ix1:ix1+na] ]

print ( slice(ix1,ix1+na) )
aa [ slice(ix1,ix1+na) ]

print ( (slice(ix1,ix1+na), slice(None,None) ))
aa [ (slice(ix1,ix1+na), slice(None,None))]
```

Comment: Show `aa` and `bb` so we can, more easily, visualize the action.  What are you trying to show with the 3 loop examples; they all do the same thing, except for the details of creating the `slice`.  For the ones that don't work, show the errors, and show what you learned from trying them.

Comment: Look into using `np.linspace` to generate an indexing array for the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the problem cases.  `np.s_` is just a way of creating a `slice` object.  It doesn't add any functionality:

```
In [562]: ix1
Out[562]: array([0, 2, 1, 3])
In [563]: slice(ix1,ix1+na)
Out[563]: slice(array([0, 2, 1, 3]), array([2, 4, 3, 5]), None)
In [564]: np.s_[ix1: ix1+na]
Out[564]: slice(array([0, 2, 1, 3]), array([2, 4, 3, 5]), None)
```

Using either as index is the same as (your previous loops showed the equivalence of these `slice` notations):

```
In [569]: aa[ix1:ix1+na]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-569-f4db64c86100>", line 1, in <module>
    aa[ix1:ix1+na]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

While it's possible to create a slice object with array values, it does not work in an actual index.

Think of it as the equivalent of trying to create a range of numbers:

```
In [572]: np.arange(ix1[0], ix1[0]+na)
Out[572]: array([0, 1])
In [573]: np.arange(ix1, ix1+na)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-573-94cfee666466>", line 1, in <module>
    np.arange(ix1, ix1+na)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

range between 0 and 2 is fine, but not range between the arrays.  Indexing slices must be between scalars, not arrays.

`linspace` does allow us to create multidimensional ranges:

```
In [574]: np.linspace(ix1,ix1+na,2,endpoint=False, dtype=int)
Out[574]: 
array([[0, 2, 1, 3],
       [1, 3, 2, 4]])
```

As long as the number of values is the same (here 2), the other values are just a matter of scaling or offset.

```
In [576]: ix1 + np.arange(0,2)[:,None]
Out[576]: 
array([[0, 2, 1, 3],
       [1, 3, 2, 4]])
```

That 2d linspace index can be used to index the rows of `aa`, along with a `arange` for columns:

```
In [579]: aa[Out[574],np.arange(4)]
Out[579]: 
array([[ 0,  9,  6, 15],
       [ 4, 13, 10, 19]], dtype=int32)
```

Basically the only alternative to joining multiple indexing operations is to construct a join indexing array(s).  Here it's easy to do.  In more general case, that join might itself require concatenation.

---

I asked for `aa` and `bb`.

```
In [580]: aa
Out[580]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]], dtype=int32)
In [581]: bb
Out[581]: 
array([[ 0,  9,  6, 15],
       [ 4, 13, 10, 19]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I've just tested your solution, and it works fine. Thank's for all :-)))